# Deserialize JSON Numbers into Enums

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the below enum:

```
public enum AnEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value3 = 3
}
```

And I have the below class:

```
public class AClass
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
    public List<AnEnum> Enums { get; set; }
}
```

And the below JSON string:

```
{"AString": "a string", "Enums": [1,2]}
```

How can I get an `AClass` instance out of the JSON string with the enums properly converted into the `AnEnum` type?

Comment: https://www.bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net.html

Comment: Depends on which JSON serializer you have.